# Secrets in docker-compose mounting as empty directories

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've been trying to add secrets to my docker container using docker-compose secrets without any luck.

Using this `docker-compose.yml` the secret is mounted under `/run/secrets/my_secret` as an empty directory, not as a file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  main:
    build:
      context: ./
    secrets:
      - my_secret

secrets:
  my_secret:
    file: first_secret.txt
```

I have tried to explicitly define the target and source

```
main:
  ...
  secrets:
        - source: my_secret
          target: /usr/local/secrets/custom_location
```

but it still gets added as an empty directory, why is that?

I'm aware of the limitations of using secrets in docker-compose without docker swarm and simply want to use secrets as a semantic way to define secrets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the ability to use secrets in docker-compose is still a work in progress (thus, doesn't work). But you may be able to use a workaround using a Dockerfile.

There's an in depth tutorial about how to do this here: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/build-secrets-docker-compose/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the container (`docker container rm …`), then run `docker compose up` again.

Source: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4865#issuecomment-468644938 (worked for me).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I forgot to create the secret file, in this example it would be first_secret.txt, just before starting the service. This caused the mount to create a folder on my local folder with the same name as the file I specified and I got the same error message as above.